# Test cases for go and appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, tdd, go

I am using Go and appengine, and now I would like to do some test cases.

I tried using gos standard test package, 
Files (both "package hello"):

```
hello/http.go
hello/http_test.go
```

Problem: I cannot run `go test hello`. The closest I have got is `go test  hello/http_test.go` which works if I do not make any calls to `http.go`, which is quite pointless. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting development: as of 1.8.6 using service stubs for testing has been integrated into the SDK through the `"appengine/aetest"` package. This works largely like the above via a "testing" context. [More info](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting)

Comment: This is the officially Google supported method of testing, however it lacks some features available in appenginetesting.

Comment: I would say so. We need to run [go get](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287315) to make it works.

Answer (score 15):

## [github.com/mzimmerman/appenginetesting](https://github.com/mzimmerman/appenginetesting)

### Installation

1. [Install Go](http://golang.org/doc/install)
2. Set the Go Environmental Variables *(Your path may vary)*:

   ```
   export GOPATH=~/gopath
   export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
   ```
3. Download the [Google App Engine SDK for Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go)
4. Set the Google App Engine Environmental Variables *(Your path may vary)*:

   ```
   export APPENGINE_SDK=$HOME/appengine
   export PATH=$PATH:$APPENGINE_SDK
   ```
5. Symlink the `appengine` and `appengine_internal` dirctories:

   ```
   ln -s $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/src/pkg/appengine $GOPATH/src/pkg/
   ln -s $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/src/pkg/appengine_internal $GOPATH/src/pkg/
   ```
6. Install [appenginetesting](https://github.com/mzimmerman/appenginetesting)

   ```
   go get github.com/mzimmerman/appenginetesting
   ```

## Writing test

**appengintesting** provides a fake `appengine.Context`. Behind the scenes It's starts up a Python development server and runs the request through it, so tests can be a little bit slow **(seconds instead of milliseconds)**. To use it in tests you write something like

```
import "github.com/mzimmerman/appenginetesting"
...
c := appenginetesting.NewContext(nil)
```

You can then use `c` as you would use an actual `appengine.Context`. This works will in the test file, but it won't work with contexts that you create by calling `appengine.NewContext(r)`

The strategy that I'm using in [gaego](https://github.com/gaego) is to import the context from a custom package instead of `appengine`. This allows me to use an `appengine.Context` when the build is for App Engine and use `appenginetesting.Context` when the build is for the test suit.

By setting the following build flags:

- context_appengine.go `// +build appengine`
- context_testing.go `// +build !appengine`

The compiler will decide which file it would like to load. [Example](https://github.com/gaego/context). This techinique was taken form [Gorilla](https://github.com/gorilla/context)

Then instead of import from `appengine` I import from my package E.g.

```
import (
  github.com/gaego/context
)

..
c := context.NewContext(r)
..
```

That last thing that needs to be mentioned is that you must explicitly close the context, otherwise the python processes will continue to run. You terminate the process by calling:

```
defer c.Close()
```

For more examples please view:

[context_test.go](https://github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting/blob/master/context_test.go)

[recorder_test.go](https://github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting/blob/master/recorder_test.go)

**Edit:** Takuya Ueda has created a brunch that works with the latest SDK

**Edit2:** [Joshua Marsh](https://github.com/icub3d) maintains a fork that is compatible with the latest SDK

**Edit3:** [Matt Zimmerman](https://github.com/mzimmerman) maintains a fork with additional features over the standard aetest package (Login/Logout & Task Queues)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I don't get this at all. Googled it and could not find any instructions how to use it (http://code.google.com/p/gae-go-testing/ is mostly misleading).

Comment: @OlaAndersson I've update my answer to include setup and usage. Please, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Works, thank you! Some things I had to add: I also needed to copy "code.google.com" folder just like appengine and appengine_internals.

Comment: Hopefully this will be part of the go appengine setup in the future.

Comment: @OlaAndersson I'm glad it worked! Thank you for mentioning the `code.google.com/p/goprotobuf` package I have updated the answer to include it. From comments on the mailing list it appears that `appenginetesting` will appear in the sdk, I think that the AEGo team just has a lot on their plate at the moment. Hopefully Google will provide them with more resources soon.

Comment: @OlaAndersson I am unable to get these instructions to work on OSX. I get the following errors:
go get github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting
package github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting
 imports bufio: unrecognized import path "bufio"
package github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting
 imports bytes: unrecognized import path "bytes"
package github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting

Comment: Im afraid I cannot help you, in my latest project I did not bother to set up testing that involved context. Too messy. Hopefully appengine will support it one day so it will be as easy as "go test".

Comment: @mzimmerman, Thank you for the edit. It was rejected by others before I could approve it, so I had to make the changes manually. Please let me know me know if I missed anything.