# Proper GOPATH to include App Engine libraries from App Engine SDK?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to write an app for App Engine using the Go SDK, but it seems to have a funny relationship to unit testing. People have [written](https://github.com/tenntenn/gae-go-testing) [libraries](https://github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting) around [this original, outdated](https://code.google.com/p/gae-go-testing/) set of tools, but every time I try to install them, depending on the Go command I use I run into one of two problems:

- From the standard `go`: Can't locate 'appengine' or 'appengine_internal'
- From the SDK's `go`: not allowed to build packages. I doubt I'm supposed to be using this.

My guess is that I have to manipulate my `$GOPATH` to include a directory somewhere in the SDK so that the appengine packages are visible, but I've tried many variations (such as `$SDK/goroot`, `$SDK/goroot/src`, etc.) and none of them seem to work.

-Generally-, what testing strategies might one suggest for App Engine for Go?

-Specifically-, how can I go about making those packages visible so that I may use the general Go tool to install libraries that depend on them (such as these testing packages) or otherwise run my own test suites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286534/test-cases-for-go-and-appengine) provides detailed installation instructions for the updated gae-go-testing. I did a quick run through and they do seem to work. Note that installation involves copying across `appengine`, `appengine_internal` and `goprotobuf` from the SDK to your local go install.

Comment: Hmm... didn't seem to work for me, but after enough tutorials failed attempts, I think something's just wrong with my environment (this time it failed because it was looking for some functions in package `os` that are present in the App Engine distro but not the vanilla Go distro).

I have a setup available for testing, but it's hack-ey and makes the app development too Design Pattern-ey, so not loving it. But it'll do.

In any case, will mark as answered, thanks for your help ^_^