# Go - cannot find package "appengine"

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have followed this guide in installing the AppEngine SDK.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/introduction

I have originally installed Go 1.2 with Brew (on OSX). I've set my paths:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/Documents/go/go_appengine:$PATH
```

I copy/pasted hello world app, and ran it with `goapp serve`. All good.

Now, as soon as I try to use `appengine`:

```
import (
    "appengine"
)
```

I get compile time error:

```
api.go:5:5: cannot find package "appengine" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/appengine (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/jan/Documents/go/src/appengine (from $GOPATH)
```

The starting guide documentation doesn't say anything about this. It seems like the SDK has its own `$GOPATH` like dir with `/src`, `/pkg` and `/bin`. I assume I would have to manually switch the `$GOPATH` between SDK and native Go all the time, which doesn't make any sense and doesn't even work for me (as I mostly work on non-appengine stuff).

I am clearly doing something wrong here. What am I missing?

EDIT:
It seems like the actual appengine server is compiling and running fine, however my entire setup is broken (testing, Vim...). Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try following the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286534/test-cases-for-go-and-appengine) provided by Kyle Finley in his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As provided by [alpe1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462981/alpe1), the following lines solve the **vim compiler go**:

```
ln -s $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/src/pkg/appengine $GOROOT/src/pkg/ 
ln -s $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/src/pkg/appengine_internal $GOROOT/src/pkg/
mkdir -p $GOROOT/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/
ln -s $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/goprotobuf
$GOROOT/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/
```

and I needed to update **gocode** [lib-path](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) (cf Options) to have the **autocompletion** for appengine:

```
gocode set lib-path "$APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine"
```

Comment: The only problem is, the 3rd party libraries that I use are compiled for 1.2 and GAE uses 1.1.2 so `goapp serve` gives me errors now. How could I fix that?

Comment: Don't do this. You should not intermingle a regular Go installation with the Go App Engine SDK.

Answer (score 2):

For testing appengine, consider [`"appengine/aetest"`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/appengine-go/appengine/aetest), which replaces the testing framework mentioned in other answers about this issue.

As for `vim`, let's avoid symlinking between distinct `GOROOT` directories. That's a recipe for bugs of the worst kind and sort: Slightly mismatched library dependencies. Have you considered simply exporting a different `GOROOT` before you launch `vim`? You could drop it into an alias trivially:

```
# You could of course drop this in your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or .zshrc
$ alias appvim="export GOROOT=$APPENGINE_SDK/goroot && vim"
```

All `syntastic` does is look in `$GOROOT/src` for the relevant includes. By changing `$GOROOT` to be the appengine SDK's, you're going to check the correct libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the packages with `google.golang.org` eg.

`"google.golang.org/appengine"`

Works with version 1.9.35.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of the Go App Engine SDK you are using. Make sure it's the most recent from https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go.

You should be able to run `goapp serve` (or `goapp build`, `goapp test`, etc.) without any changes to the extracted SDK. You should only need to add the path to go_appengine to your `PATH`.

You should be able to have a single `GOPATH` for both regular Go and App Engine.

Your error message implies that the GOROOT is `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec`. Is that when you invoke `goapp`? That shouldn't happen. Does anything change if you use the full path `$HOME/Documents/go/go_appengine/goapp`?

Comment: You are correct. This has all changed with version 1.7.4 as described [here](https://blog.golang.org/the-app-engine-sdk-and-workspaces-gopath)

Answer (score 0):

Building on Christopher's answer, `gocode` looks in `$GOROOT/pkg` for a path matching your architecture (e.g. `$GOROOT/pkg/darwin_amd64`). However, the code directory in AppEngine's setup is suffixed with _appengine (e.g. `$GOROOT/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine`). You can fix this discrepancy by creating a simlink:

```
export APPENGINE_SDK=/your/appengine/sdk/directory/go_appengine
ln -s $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/pkg/your_architecture_appengine $APPENGINE_SDK/goroot/pkg/your_architecture_amd64
```

Be sure to replace the AppEngine directory and architectures above with your own.

After doing this, create an alias to change GOROOT and start vim

```
alias appvim="export GOROOT=$APPENGINE_SDK/goroot && vim"
```

as Christopher mentioned in his comment.