# How to fix Google-cloud-sdk 156.0.0 "There are too many files in your application for changes in all of them to be monitored."?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I just installed Go 1.6.4 and google-cloud-sdk 1.56.0.0 on osX.

When I attempt to run the local dev_server I get the following warning.

/Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/mtime_file_watcher.py:156: UserWarning: There are too many files in your application for changes in all of them to be monitored. You may have to restart the development server to see some changes to your files.

How do I fix this?

Here is the project, there are only 4 files:

```
$ ls
total 32
drwxrwxrwx   6 Bryan  staff   204 May 23 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 Bryan  staff   340 May 25 18:39 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 Bryan  staff    69 Mar 22 09:40 app.yaml
-rw-r--r--   1 Bryan  staff   554 Mar 28 09:26 index.yaml
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 Bryan  staff  3015 May 25 18:36 skincare.go
-rw-r--r--   1 Bryan  staff   870 May  3 09:18 skincare_test.go
```

I'm also having a problem that "go get" attempts to compile the code instead of downloading the remote packages "google.golang.org/appengine".

$ go get

```
# import "google.golang.org/appengine" is ignored and "go get" yields this error:
./skincare.go:31: undefined: appengine.Context
```

EDIT additional info: 
I attempted to to force the update with the -u flag:
$ go get -u

```
package skincarereview: directory "/Users/Bryan/go/src/skincarereview" is not using a known version control system
```

This is the error output when I attempt to run the local server:

```
$  /Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml
INFO     2017-05-30 14:27:31,722 devappserver2.py:692] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-05-30 14:27:31,785 api_server.py:272] Starting API server at: http://localhost:60703
INFO     2017-05-30 14:27:31,789 dispatcher.py:205] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-05-30 14:27:31,793 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
/Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/mtime_file_watcher.py:156: UserWarning: There are too many files in your application for changes in all of them to be monitored. You may have to restart the development server to see some changes to your files.
  'There are too many files in your application for '
ERROR    2017-05-30 14:27:36,123 go_runtime.py:182] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /Users/Bryan/go/src/skincarereview -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot -gopath /Users/Bryan/go -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_rebuild -unsafe -binary_name _go_app -extra_imports appengine_internal/init -work_dir /var/folders/mw/0y88j8_54bjc93d_lg3120qw0000gp/T/tmpEOVMVuappengine-go-bin -gcflags -I,/Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine -ldflags -L,/Users/Bryan/go/src/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine skincare.go skincare_test.go)
/var/folders/mw/0y88j8_54bjc93d_lg3120qw0000gp/T/tmpEOVMVuappengine-go-bin/skincare.go:31: undefined: "google.golang.org/appengine".Context

2017/05/30 10:27:36 go-app-builder: build timing: 0×skip (5ms total), 11×compile (2.128s total), 0×link (0 total)
2017/05/30 10:27:36 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 2
```

Comment: My guess is that the dev server monitors all .go files in GOPATH in addition to those in the app directory.  By default `go get` does not download if the package is already on GOPATH.  Use `go get -u` to force update from the source.

Comment: So does that mean my GOPATH ( /Users/Bryan/go ) is wrong?

Comment: I don't think the GOPATH is wrong.  Also, this is just a warning about auto recompilation.  Everything else should work.

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions in your other question when installing `google-cloud-sdk`. The SDK itself goes in your `home` directory, NOT your `$GOPATH`. Technically it doesn't matter where the SDK resides as long as it is in your `$PATH`, but it should definitely NOT be in your `$GOPATH`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591772/where-does-go-look-for-google-cloud-sdk-what-should-gopath-be/43641355#43641355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only used an older version of appengine sdk, but I believe below is still true.

The main issue is that you have google-cloud-sdk inside your GOPATH. This should not be necessary. I have it installed in my path. But even if not installed it should be resolving it's location relative to the executable or script you are running and should find all required sdk files properly. At the same time SDK is roughly 7500 files and you only need to have more than 10000 (approx) in your GOPATH to get that "to many files" warning. So, if you have another (e.g. older) copy of SDK or other big project inside same GOPATH, you are pretty much guaranteed to exceed the threshold. Just locate /Users/Bryan/go in Finder and use "Get Info" to count files.

So, either move appengine SDK outside of your GOPATH. Or make a new folder, export it as your new GOPATH and move your project files (but not SDK) to that new folder. This should fix the "too many files issue".

The other issue is that your app actually fails to build. And as you have already figured out yourself the (immediate) issue is missing appengine package.

But the correct way of getting google.golang.org/appengine is as follows:

`go get google.golang.org/appengine`

Though keep in mind that GOPATH must be set correctly *before* running the above command. It will fetch google.golang.org/appengine and all it's dependencies.

Once you have retrieved all required packages (and fixed errors, if any) it should compile and run without issues.

Comment: I thought google-cloud-sdk was expected to be @ ~/go/src    Should ~/go/src only contain my code and dependencies AND exclude google-cloud-sdk?

Comment: go get seems to require $GOPATH:   go get google.golang.org/appengine

Comment: package google.golang.org/appengine: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath

Comment: Most 3d party sdk or libraries in go are packaged as a go package and you would "go get" them into your src folder. But google-cloud-sdk is not just go package, but full blown sdk. So, it does not need to be in your GOPATH. Think of GOPATH as a project folder in other languages. google-cloud-sdk is rather akin to Platform SDK in Windows or JDK for Java. Neither need to have a copy in each project folder.

Comment: $GOPATH is just an environment variable. Just set it to be your project folder. E.g. `export GOPATH=/Users/Bryan/go` in your example, if you're using command line (such as Terminal). Then just run `go get` commands from the same Terminal window.

Comment: This post is confusing....isn't running:
go get google.golang.org/appengine
going to put app engine under go/src/
and doesn't that contradict what you are advising??

Comment: @Dewey Please see comments above. Google App Engine SDK for Go is an SDK, not just a package. See (and follow) installation instructions in App Engine SDK documentation. However, google.golang.org/appengine is a package. It might be actually provided by newer versions of SDK, but at least at the time of writing it wasn't. Thus needed to be fetched into GOPATH using `go get`.

Answer (score 3):

With my current sdk version (`Google Cloud SDK 171.0.0`) `dev_appserver.py` has one option named `enable_watching_go_path`.

Setting it to `False` removed the warning.

The command I use is:
`dev_appserver.py --enable_watching_go_path=False server/app.yml`

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding error occurs when mtime_file_watcher.py tries to monitor all files under "GOPATH" but has too many files, so use the skip_files option of app.yaml to check vendor, node_modules and arbitrary number of files Can be avoided by excluding many projects to be monitored.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files

```
skip_files:
- .*node_modules
- .*vendor
- .*project-name-having-too-many-files
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using just the App Engine SDK for Go (1.9.54), not the Cloud SDK, but have the same problem [[Goapp serve - Warning: There are too many files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44703952/8181815]).

I solved it by moving large packages and repositories to `vendor/` dir.