# Goapp serve - Warning: There are too many files

Tags: google-app-engine, go

After upgraded to go_appengine SDK version 1.9.54, I always get following warning, even just one or two .go files are used in the app directory. As a result, file changes are not automatically detected and app is not rebuilt.

`$ goapp serve`

go_appengine-1.9.54/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/mtime_file_watcher.py:182: UserWarning: There are too many files in your application for changes in all of them to be monitored. You may have to restart the development server to see some changes to your files.
  'There are too many files in your application for '

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Google-cloud-sdk 156.0.0 "There are too many files in your application for changes in all of them to be monitored."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208305/how-to-fix-google-cloud-sdk-156-0-0-there-are-too-many-files-in-your-applicatio)

Comment: Seems it's related, however I'm just using the original App Engine SDK for Go  on OS X, not the whole Google Cloud SDK with `app-engine-go` component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `vendor/` directory for large package sources used in my project, such `golang.org` or `google.golang.org` repositories. Using `devappserver2.py` via `$ goapp serve`, file changes in vendor directories are ignored. Works for go version 1.6 >

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem occured, when I have a mixed content in the parent directory, including npm project and `node_modules` directory.To solve the problem, I changed `_IGNORED_PREFIX` variable in `go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/watcher_common.py` file as following:

`Line 24: _IGNORED_PREFIX = ('.', 'node_modules')`

Using appengine-1.9.57.

Answer (score 0):

A corresponding error occurs when the file under the "$GOPATH" directory is subject to file monitoring and the number of files is large.
In my case, by specifying "vendor" or a project with many files in "skip_files" option of "app.yaml", I was able to prevent the corresponding error from occurring.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files

```
skip_files:
- .*node_modules
- .*vendor
- .*project-name-having-too-many-files
```