# `cannot find package "appengine" error` when using VS code

Tags: google-app-engine, visual-studio-code

By following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/getting-started/creating-guestbook) I created a go lang project and opened it by `Visual Studio Code`.

The code itself works fine I can run the server, but somehow VS Code shows

```
cannot find package "appengine" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/appengine (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/ironsand/go/src/appengine (from $GOPATH)
```

I thought I must set `GOROOT` for the Google App Engine, but according to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43641355/1536527) I shouldn't.

How to make VS Code recognize google app engine library properly?

### More info

The `appengine` package exists in `~/dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8/‌​src/appengine`

I'm using `macOS Sierra 10.12.6`.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, does "appengine" exist in either of those directories?  /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/ or /Users/ironsand/go/src/ ?

Comment: Try this tutorial how to add GAE as extension: https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart

Comment: @ironsand were you able to resolve this VS issue? If so it is recommended that you post your answer as the solution here to better help the community.

Comment: @Helpful No there is no "appengine" in these directories, and the package exists in ` ~/dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8/src/appengine`.

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa The tutorial is for `Visual Studio`, not for `Visual Studio Code`.

Comment: @Jordan Not yet.

Comment: What is your OS? linux?

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa MacOS Sierra. I'll add info to my question.

Comment: @ironsand I hope that my answer helped you

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa Sorry I didn't have time for this.

Comment: I am facing similar issue with mux on visual studio code for MAC. Below suggestion is for python and not for go..

Answer (score 3):

I did use that tutorial and it's working on my Mac via terminal and via VS Code.

You may follow this tutorial to be able use VS code to deploy GAE app with python:
[Deploy GAE app with VS code](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/debugging_google-app-engine/)

• Dont forget to update path of `dev_appserver.py` in `tasks.json`.

If that didn't work out, you would need to re-install/init `google-cloud-sdk`.

Note that it's necessary to provide root privileges during installing/initializing  in order to allow installer script to add paths properly.

Last thing: avoid tilde expansion `~` in path. Use absolute path in config.( in general absolute path must be used always unless there is a reason to use relative address with tilde )

Good luck,'.

Comment: This is a tutorial for `python` and I'm using `go`. Am I misunderstanding?